# mail with php pear semi-randomly corrupts characters

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm sending email through pear, but the end result some times has corrupted characters. Despite the email being roughly the same (a couple words change, the recipients e-mail address) the corrupted characters are not always in the same place of the html body. You can see some weird ? characters there. The email is sent as follows through php PEAR:

Example of received on email on gmail account with corrupted body. Some times links get corrupted (it adds a space and/or x0D / %0D character - which is carriage return). Every time, just a word gets corrupted like below. Some times the corrupted character is in the subject, but rarely.

```
Received: from localhost (some.domain.com [1.2.3.4]) (Authenticated sender: xxx@mydomain.com) by blabla.domain.com (ESMTP) with ESMTPSA for <recipient@gmail.com>; Tue, 25 Jan 2022 01:06:05 +0200 (EET)
From: xxx@mydomain.com
To: recipient@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 01:06:04 +0200
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Mailer: PHP/7.x.x
Reply-To: xxx@mydomain.com
Subject: my subject

<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="el"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head><body>...Content in greek here... όμορφος, πα�
 �άτε εκεί ... content here</body></html>
```

instead of the word "πατάτε"

php_script_sending_mail.php

```
                $UserMesssage = "some greek content here which gets corrupted at usually one word";
                $MAILto      = $varEmail;
                $MAILmessage = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"el\"/><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/></head><body>";
                $MAILmessage .= $UserMesssage;
                $MAILmessage .= "</body></html>";

                mail_new($MAILto, $MAILsubject, $MAILmessage);
```

fn_mail.php

```
    function mail_new($to, $subject, $message) {
        require_once "Mail.php";
        
        $from = "xxx@mydomain.com";

        $host = "mailgate.isp.com";
        $username = "xxx@mydomain.com";
        $password = "pass";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Date' => date('r', time()), 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/'.phpversion(), 'Reply-To' => 'xxx@mydomain.com', 'Subject' => '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=');
        $smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
     
        $mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
     
    }
```

Both files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to consider these too:
1. Adding `MIME-Version: 1.0` to headers to support different type of chars and non text data.
2. Another encoding like `charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: mime version header doesn't solve the problem. I cannot use another charset, I need utf8

Comment: Just for the future when you say using `pear` on its own it means nothing, pear is just a extension framework for PHP you should always have a pear extension, i would also say it's rare you want a server to send mail nowadays spam filters are a pain in the arse, you're better of using an external service like mailgun because they will tell you everything is correct and will be coming from a mail server that is semi-whitelisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install PEAR module **Mail/mime** and set additional mime headers, i.e. **text_charset** and **html_charset**.

```php
<?php

function mail_new($to, $subject, $message) {
    require_once "Mail.php";
    require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

    $from = "xxx@mydomain.com";

    $host = "mailgate.isp.com";
    $username = "xxx@mydomain.com";
    $password = "pass";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Date' => date('r', time()), 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/'.phpversion(), 'Reply-To' => 'xxx@mydomain.com', 'Subject' => '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=');

    $mime = new Mail_mime();
    $mime->setHTMLBody($message);
    $mimeparams = array();
    $mimeparams['text_charset'] = "UTF-8";
    $mimeparams['html_charset'] = "UTF-8";
    $message = $mime->get($mimeparams);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

    $mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);

}

mail_new('xxx@mydomain.com',
         'Test Message',
        '<html><body>Α α, Β β, Γ γ, Δ δ, Ε ε, Ζ ζ, Η η, Θ θ, Ι ι, Κ κ, Λ λ, Μ μ, Ν ν, Ξ ξ, Ο ο, Π π, Ρ ρ, Σ σ/ς, Τ τ, Υ υ, Φ φ, Χ χ, Ψ ψ, Ω ω.</body></html>'
        );
```

Comment: I thought emails were now supposed to have multiple mimes, ASCII, UTF-8 and UTF-16 so emoji could be handled if clients that support it falling back down them to the worst support for email clients?

Comment: @Barkermn01 I really don't know much about emojis, but you could use multiple mimes for adding, for example, text/html and a text/plain versions of the same email. In this case we are just adding a text/html version, but we get to add the all-important character set information that was required.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are using a unix server(or localhost) and have full access to it. I am not sure if the below will solve your issue, give it a try.

Step 1) Find out which locales are installed in your [find ubuntu locale list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server), in terminal:

```
locale -a
```

if greek is not installed, try to install it:

```
sudo locale-gen el_GR
sudo locale-gen el_GR.utf8
```

To update the locale info:

```
sudo update-locale
```

Step 2) Try to set the locale at the top of your script:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "el_GR.utf8");
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "el_GR.utf8");
```

You can get the list of locales used by using:

```
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
```

According to the documenation:

- LC_COLLATE for string comparison, see strcoll()
- LC_CTYPE for character classification and conversion, for example strtoupper()

Maybe ***Mail.php*** is using one of the above functions affected by either **LC_CTYPE**  or **LC_COLLATE**.

Keep in mind about the warning on the documentation:

> The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API , you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale().

References

[setlocale php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: I'm running windows server. Thank you for your reply, the solution was the above one